# 2D vector math with direction and velocity

Tags: ios, math, vector, 2d

Heyo!

I'm starting to create games on iOS and I'm trying a Breakout-clone for start. As practice I wanted a ball to bounce around in a rectangle so I get my head around simple collision, direction and velocity.

My ball got the following:

```
Point position; // x, y
float direction;
float velocity;
```

In my "update" function, I want to move the ball in the current direction. What is the next position considering the velocity and direction?

Are there any helpers in some built-in frameworks in iOS?

I would really like to learn more about 2D-math so if someone got some reasources I would really appreciate if you send me a link.

Comment: Why store "velocity" and "direction"? It's much easier to store velocity_x and velocity_y.

Comment: Sounds good. But then I'd have to add some kind of force to calculate the velocity, right?

Comment: Emil, your last comment makes no sense at all. Depending on how you define direction, the next position will be something like `x=x+vel*cos(dir)*deltat; y=y+vel*sin(dir)*deltat`. But it's easier to work with vel_x and vel_y.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the next position considering the velocity and direction?

Note that velocity already has direction; it is a vector

Bearing that in mind, your new position is:

```
position = CGPointMake(position.x + velocity.x, position.y + velocity.y)
```

Make velocity a CGPoint and make your direction variable redundant.

Comment: Sounds good. But then I'd have to add some kind of force to calculate the velocity, right?

Comment: That depends how you _want_ your program to work. If velocity is constant, you won't need any force

Comment: Ok, I understand. But I don't get how this will help with my bouncing ball. Let's say the ball starts at the center bottom of a standing rectangle, and start in an "north-west" direction and will travel 1 unit of length each frame. The velocity will then be x = -1, y = 1. Right? And the angle would be 135 degrees if "east" is considerd 0. When the ball hits the left wall, then what? I would like to mirror the incoming angle and let the next velocity be x = 1, y = 1. But how can I get these numbers without some kind of angle/direction/rotation? Maybe I'm just confused...

Comment: You'll have to detect the collision, (Search `collision detection`), calculate the new velocity (search `reflection vector`).

Answer (score 0):

Convert the direction and velocity into a vector, scale it for time, and then add it to the current position, accounting for obstacles encountered along the path.